# GATK Variant Filtration file Anopheles gambiae s.s

Tags: filtering, variant, gatk

I am trying to find an open source vcf of known variants for Anopheles gambiae s.s, which I can use for filtering with GATK VQSR (GATK Variant Filtration), instead of using hard filtering. Is this available anywhere?

I am also looking for this Anopheles gambiae P4 file:
gs://vo_agam_production/resources/observatory/ag.allsites.nonN.vcf.gz
which is referenced in the SNP genotyping pipeline https://github.com/malariagen/pipelines/blob/v0.0.4/docs/specs/snp-genotyping-vector.md. I'm not able to download this directly.

I'd be very grateful for some help!
Thank you!

I have searched and have been unable to find these files. I tried downloading from gs and was denied.